# banner/header for site that's using visual editor

Tags: wordpress, header

Few questions about this widget/header banner?

1. How do I extend the header throughout the full row (width) of screen? (like the green menu bar on top)
2. When I have it in the footer, and full width row, the image sits outside the widget- How do I make sure this doesn't happen when I extend the header widget to full row?
3. I tried adding shite background but that isn't doing anything; how do I make the color white?

http://www.localgreeneats.com/category/blog/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this file
http://www.localgreeneats.com/wp-content/themes/boldgrid-evolv/inc/boldgrid-theme-framework/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css

why don't you add the following?

```
.well {
margin-top: 10%; /* this will work on both mobile and desktop */
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you expand?   The link you added is a lot of code I can't decipher but the code doesn't seem normal.